# Certain firefox downloads freezing constantly

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, firefox

I bought a premium account on an HTTP filesharing website a couple weeks ago. I've been having problems using it though. When I'm on it, the downloads will often pause randomly. It doesn't happen if I download as a free user. What happens is it downloads a few MB's, but then as the speed gets faster it suddenly stops completely. However, firefox doesn't cancel the download, and if I pause/resume it, it starts again. The only problem is a few MB's later it happens again.

It may seem like an obvious problem of the site itself, but I contacted their support and they claim they don't limit premium user's speeds in any way. I don't have too much to compare this situation with, because I usually don't have the opportunity to download files of any size with fast speeds like this. The only thing I could compare it to would be Bittorrent, where I can sometimes have speeds >3 Mb/s and have no problems.

My router is a Linksys E3200 and my modem is a Motorola SB5101 Surfboard. My network card is a Intel Centrino Advanced-N + WiMAX 6250 and I'm on Windows 7